# launchctl unload say: Could not find specified service

Tags: mac, macos-highsierra, launchctl

I'm trying to make a plist file in order to start nginx on boot. When starting nginx with `launchctl` it starts the service. But it cannot unload it, and print "Could not find specified service".

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx
me (...) grep nginx

$ sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist 
(no output)

$ ps aux | grep nginx
me (...) grep nginx
nobody (...) nginx: worker process
root (...) nginx: master process /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx

$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist 
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist: Could not find specified service
```

This is the content of /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist

```
$ cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
                       "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key><string>nginx</string>
    <key>Program</key><string>/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key><true/>
    <key>NetworkState</key><true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key><string>/opt/nginx/logs/system.log</string>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key><true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Any help appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm facing it at the moment and can't figure that out either

Answer (score 6):

Try removing the `sudo` and just run:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/nginx.plist
```

When attempting to unload some LaunchDaemons, it will return `"Could not find specified service"` if using `sudo`.

Comment: `Warning: Expecting a LaunchAgents path since the command was ran as user. Got LaunchDaemons instead.
`launchctl bootout` is a recommended alternative.
Unload failed: 5: Input/output error
Try running `launchctl bootout` as root for richer errors.`